# Playing a random Youtube video from a predefined php array list

Tags: php, youtube

So i want to play a video from a array list in php.
This is what i got now, tough i tried everything but it doesnt want to work,

```
<div id="random_video">
  <?php 
    $strings= array('5mPggfOb6Us', '3oT9PQcFZKc', 'wCA6jCUbaFQ', 'zi3ZWe_kTHU', 'zISkHobZ8OM');
    $random_str = $strings[array_rand($strings)];
  ?>
  <iframe width="329" height="185" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php $random_str ?>?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</div>
```

Thanks for help in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna have to print it.

`<?php echo $random_str; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: generate a random key first, then choose the string with the random key:

```
$strings= array('5mPggfOb6Us', '3oT9PQcFZKc', 'wCA6jCUbaFQ', 'zi3ZWe_kTHU', 'zISkHobZ8OM');
$random_key = array_rand($strings, 1);
$random_str = $strings[$random_key];
```

Then change the embedded string like this:

```
<iframe width="329" height="185" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $random_str ?>?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```